# Tiered Charging IF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a cell to compute a percentage of a value based on the value itself.

For example:

- Below £100,000: 0.25% + £45.00
- From £100,000 to £1,000,000: 0.15%
- Above £1,000,000: 0.10%

How can I write a formula to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use 2 helper tables so you can easily add more conditions in the future if needed:

```
=B2*VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$4,2,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(B2,$H$2:$I$4,2,TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Or just use `IF`:

```
=IF(B22<100000,B22*0.0025+45,IF(B22<1000000,B22*0.0015,B22*0.001))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work for what I want or at least it doesnt give me the result i'm looking for. I have this so far:- =IF(B4>100000,"0.15%","0.25%")

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? =IF(B4<100000,"0.25%",IF(B4<1000000,"0.15%","0.1%"))