# Tiered Charging Structure Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a tiered charge calculator.

We have a provider giving us special terms on investments that fall within the below banding.

- First 50k is charged at 0.35%
- 50k to £500k is charged at 0.20%
- 500k to 1m is charged at 0.15%
- 1m + is charged at 0.10%

I want a formula to take into account the first 50k being charged at 0.35% then whatever falls in between the banding to be calculated and weighted.

I have attached a screengrab of what I have currently but I'm not confident it works and when I go above 500k it doesn't work. Thanks

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1>=$A$3:$A$6),(B1-$A$3:$A$6),$D$3:$D$6)/100
```

Comment: I would make a table of the charge bands and use vlookup().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tiered Charging IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044682/tiered-charging-if-statements)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya How is the linked question a duplicate (if you look at my answer)? It probably is a duplicate but not of that one.

Comment: By changing some context of the post does nt makes it different sir, please check the duplicate post. It is same question but asked in a different way. Threshold calculations or tiered Chargings have been solved multiple times,

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table with the conditions you can use a `FILTER` formula to retrieve the charge:

`=FILTER(tblTerms[charge],(tblTerms[from]<=A8)*(tblTerms[to]>A8))`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Tiered Charging Structure Formula

Formula in `C1`

```
=INDEX(B1*$D$3:$D$6/100,MATCH(TRUE,B1>=$A$3:$A$6,0))
```

[image]

- The crucial part is the match `MATCH(TRUE,B1>=$A$3:$A$6,0)`.
- If you need the number subtracted, surely you can figure out `B1-B1*$D$3:$D$6/100` or some other version of it.